# Autosuggest / Autocomplete with multiple indexes and Lucene.Net?

Tags: autocomplete, lucene.net, autosuggest

Does anyone have any suggestions when it comes to building an Autosuggestion / Autocomplete search on multiple indexes?

Update: I found this [link](http://www.rick-sammons.com/post/Multiple-Index-Search-with-LuceneNET.aspx) that may be how I need to approach my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MultiReader` to read from several readers. Here's an example to iterate all indexed terms in a field named "data". You specify where you want to start the enumeration in the call to `.Terms(...)`. You could specify another starting point to match what the user has entered so far, to provide autocompletion on a term level.

```
using System;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Store;

public static class ConsoleApp {
    private static readonly String FieldName = "data";

    public static void Main() {
        var ram1 = Create(prefix: "b");
        var ram2 = Create(prefix: "a");

        var multiReader = new MultiReader(new[] {
            IndexReader.Open(ram1, readOnly: true),
            IndexReader.Open(ram2, readOnly: true)
        });

        var termsEnum = multiReader.Terms(new Term(FieldName));
        do {
            var term = termsEnum.Term();
            if (term.Field() != FieldName)
                break;

            Console.WriteLine(term.Text());
        } while (termsEnum.Next());
    }

    public static Directory Create(String prefix) {
        var dir = new RAMDirectory();

        var writer = new IndexWriter(dir, a: new KeywordAnalyzer(), create: true, mfl: IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            var doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field(FieldName, prefix + i, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }
        writer.Close();

        return dir;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to acheive this same thing using LinqToLucene?

Comment: Linq to Lucene does queries, not term enumeration.